# IE7 cutting off image

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

Hi all
I have 3 divs with rollover images inside them stacked vertically inside my main content div. IE7 is chopping off about three quarters of the bottom div and I can't figure out why. It displays perfectly in all other browsers (even IE6) but IE7 just won't display properly.
This is my first website so I still have a lot to learn. I've managed to fix the other IE bugs but just can't figure this one out. Any help appreciated!

```
.main_content {
    float: left;
    width: 816px;
    background-image: url(Images/evokedesign_bg_tile.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.portfolio_buttons {
    float: left;
    width: 634px;
}
```

Site link: http://evokedesignstudio.com.au/Portfolio.html

Comment: can you please post the HTML?

Comment: If possible, post a link to your live site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you posted a link to your live site, I found the answer very quickly:

- On `.gallery`, remove the `height: 400px` rule.
- Done.

This fixes IE7, and nothing changes in IE8/other browsers.

Comment: Hi Thitydot - Thanks so much for the help. Who knew the answer would be so simple lol! like I said - still have a lot to learn ;)

Comment: @Kimberley: It was no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have got your `.page_container` set to a fixed height of **730px**.

Try updating the **CSS** to

```
.page_container {
padding: 0px;
min-height: 730px;
height:730px;
}
```

Same with the `.gallery` as @thirtydot said. Either remove the height all together or update it to min-height and height below (see above example).

By placing the `height` below the `min-height` in your stylesheet, any browser that doesn't recognise the `min-height` tag (IE6) will then register the `height` below it as a backup.

Comment: Thanks for the help Dan. Removing the height from the .gallery rule has done the trick.